# Kloudless Python Webhook

Tags: python, rest, kloudless

[Simple WebHooks Receiver](https://blog.kloudless.com/2014/10/19/getting-started-with-kloudless-webhooks/) I'm following this tutorial on webhooks with kloudless. I downloaded ngrok  and set a URL to point to a local server and then setup a server using `Python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`. I ran POST requests with the URL ngrok gave me and was able to see/navigate my local directories. I want to use this script to verify the webhook sender and launch a task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, request, abort

import hmac
import base64
import hashlib
import threading

app = Flask('demo_app')
APP_ID = ''
API_KEY = ''
@app_route('/webook', methods=['POST'])     //FIX. @app_route should be @app.route
def receiver():
# Verify the Request Signature
digest = hmac.new(API_KEY,msg=request.data,digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
sig = base64.b64encode(digest)
if not sig == request.headers.get('X-Kloudless-Signature'):
abort(403)

# Since the request is verified we can actually do something
account_id = request.form.get('account')
if account_id:
    threading.Thread(target=process_account, args=(account_id,)).start()
# In order to verify that the endpoint is alive you should always return your application id with a 200 OK response
    return APP_ID

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run()
```

I'm getting an error

`@app_route('/webhook ', methods=['POST'])
NameError: name 'app_route' is not defined`

Do I specify the URL that ngrok set up using localhost for the `@app_route`?

**UPDATE**

the `@app_route`should be left as `/webhook` the external URL should be the `https://046f3f46.ngrok.io/webhook` as an example. 
Now I'm trying to figure why after I added this external URL to my dev portal under current webhooks, it is giving me an unsupported `POST` method when clearly the app supports it.

**UPDATE**

So the Python `SimpleHTTPSever` does not support the POST method.
I have found that this [python server](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial) does support the GET and POST methods(well it's supposed to), however I'm getting a 405 error code which again is an unsupported method. Not sure what's going on, it has to be something in the environment.

Comment: Apologies for the error in the blog post. We'll get on fixing that. Could you try this for the webhooks receiver: https://gist.github.com/vinodc/ee4933114e988bc02995 It should support both GET and POST Note that I am using `app.route` and not `app_route`. You can then add in signature validation as you have done above.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The basic webhook receiver gist you posted works perfectly. I'm attempting to add in the signature verification and getting a key error message  in my local webserver when adding the ngrok URL to my dev portal in kloudless. Looking into it, any ideas ? @vinod

Comment: So when this line is returned os.environ["APP_ID"] it's giving a key error. I changed it to return the hard coded APP_ID, and then was able to add my ngrok/webhook URL to the dev portal and got the 200 Ok response. when entered into chrome it returns the APP_ID. will build form here @vinod

Comment: Also, trying to test using the cloud-text-editor I get an error when trying to save a test text file, when i choose whatever account(gdrive, onedrive, etc.) it gives me `TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent_id'` @vinod

Comment: still haven't had any luck with saving a file with cloud-text-editor @vinod

Comment: I've updated the cloud text editor example app to use the latest SDK and authenticator library correctly, removing incompatibilities. Could you check out the project now? Thanks.

Comment: It now runs smoothly and the `test.txt` file uploads to cloud storage of my choosing, is there a way that I could rework the js file to upload a file to multiple/all of the my connected storage accounts with one reques? @vinod

Comment: Can that change be made to the js authenticator library or should it be done elsewhere? @vinod